# How to search subdirectories that has only 1 file inside and move the file up one step to the parent directory

Tags: files, directory, move

So I have multiple subdirectories in which many of them have only 1 file and the name of the filename is the same as the subdirectory name.

```
DIR A
--DIR B
----B.zip
--DIR C
----C2.zip
----C3.zip
--DIR D
----D.zip
```

So the ideal result should be:

1. both `B.zip` and `D.zip` moved to `DIR A`
2. `DIR B` and `DIR D` is now empty and need to be removed, while `DIR C` is left alone because it contained more than 1 file

Is it something possible to do or I need to write special programming code?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome, you say - *"the name of the filename is the same as the subdirectory name"* -. Could you **[edit]** the question and reflect this in the sample?

Comment: Also, do the files have a particular extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `GNU find` utility, which traverses the directory tree and gathers information along the way. -depth option will make find do a depth-first traversal of the tree
and we come up directory names that store exactly one regular file. Then we move that file up abd tgen delete the just emptied directory.

```
find . -depth ! -name . -type d -execdir \
sh -c '
  isFileKnt_1() {
    test "$(cd "$1" && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -c /)" -eq 1
  }
  for d do 
    t=$(mktemp -d)
    isFileKnt_1 "$d" || exit 0
    mv "$d"/* "$t"/.
    rmdir "$d"
    mv "$t"/* .
  done
' find-sh {} +
```

tree -F outputs before and after the operation.

```
.
├── dirB/
│   └── dirB
├── dirC/
│   ├── file_2
│   └── file_3
└── dirD/
    └── dirD
```

```
.
├── dirB
├── dirC/
│   ├── file_2
│   └── file_3
└── dirD
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. Really appreciate it.